# Duplicate tag for [formvalidation-plugin]

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

I think that [formvalidation-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation-plugin) and [formvalidation.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation.io) point to the same validation library.

---

[formvalidation-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation-plugin) tag info is:

> Form validation jQuery plugin that allows you to validate data in popular frameworks (Bootstrap, Foundation ,Pure, Semantic UI, UIKit)
>
> This form validation jQuery plugin allow syou to make quick validation using many validation rules.
>
> Reference:
>
> - [Form validation plugin page](http://formvalidation.io/)

while [formvalidation.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation.io) tag info is:

> A jQuery plugin to validate form fields
>
> Designed for Bootstrap, Foundation, Pure, Semantic UI, UIKit
>
> More information at http://formvalidation.io/

---

I would like to suggest to make the latter synonym of the first since [formvalidation-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation-plugin) is older and a bit more used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both referring to the same jQuery validation library; in fact, both the tag wikis link to the same site.
There are even [15 questions using both the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation.io%20formvalidation-plugin?mode=all), out of 60 questions tagged [formvalidation.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation.io).

I would keep [formvalidation-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formvalidation-plugin) since it has a slightly better wiki, and it is the older tag.